# Android Azure Notification hub unregister

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm having a problem with unregistering notification hub from Azure.

I'm using method `unregister()` like this :

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

String connectionString = "xxx";
hub = new NotificationHub("xxx", connectionString, getApplicationContext());

try {
    gcm.unregister();
    hub.unregister();
    Log.d("GCM","Unregister");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
};
```

I don't get any exception in this code, but I'm still getting push notification. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: gcm.unregister() does not seem to be required. How do you register with NH, do you use templates?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't unregister from GCM.

> **Why you should rarely unregister**
>
> You should only need to unregister in rare cases, such as if you want
> an app to stop receiving messages, or if you suspect that the
> registration ID has been compromised. In general, once an app has a
> registration ID, you shouldn't need to change it.
>
> In particular, you should never unregister your app as a mechanism for
> logout or for switching between users, for the following reasons:
>
> - A registration ID isn't associated with a particular logged in user.
>   If you unregister and then re-register, GCM may return the same ID or
>   a different ID—there's no guarantee either way.
> - Unregistration may take up to 5 minutes to propagate.
> - After unregistration, re-registration may again take up to 5 minutes to propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due
>   to the state of being
>   unregistered, and after all this, messages may still go to the wrong
>   user.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#unreg-why

Since you are using Azure Notification Hub, you just need to delete registration from there, not from GCM.

Comment: hi @Andrei thank you for your answer, but can you tell me how to delete registration from azure?

Comment: try DeleteRegistrationAsync.

Comment: I too have the same issue.  I used both method of unregister notificationHub.unregisterAll(storedRegGCMId);
notificationHub.unregister(); But still I'm receiving the notifications from Azure Hub

Comment: @AbhijitKurane Late to the game here and not sure if this is different that C# but you should not be passing the GCM Registration Id to Azure Notification Hubs when trying to unregister. Azure Notification Hubs produce their own Registration Id which you would use to unregister. It is unfortunate that GCM and Azure both use the name `Registration Id` but they are not the same values.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I will try and let you know
--

Comment: I don't really care if Google doesn't want me to unregister. The user has logged out of my app, and I want to stop receiving notifications! And I am trying to unregister from the notificationhub, but it seems to be a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

In general, just using `hub.unregister()` will suffice.  Alternatively, just call `hub.register()` with an invalid tag, and it should overwrite the existing registration.

However, I've found that registrations are sometimes duplicated in the Notification Hub (same PNS, different tags/Azure Registration ID), and `unregister` only removes one of them, so you keep getting notified.  Maybe this happens when you reinstall the app, not sure.

Anyway, to solve this you can delete the registration manually (Visual Studio > Server Explorer > Notification Hubs > Select one > Device registrations tab).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a different `Thread` to unregister that device. Below way works for me correctly. Please don't forget to keep `hub` which is used to register device. In below, I generated a `HubKeeper` class and i kept that `hub` in `HubKeeper` class as static. But differently, I have used [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) instead of [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try  {
                    if (HubKeeper.hub != null) {
                        HubKeeper.hub.unregister();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
```