# Unregister tags with Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs

Tags: notifications, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I have inherited an iOS app that uses Azure Notification hubs to send notifications, however there is a snag.

The users select multiple categories for which to receive notifications (News, Sports, etc), and they can change these at any time. Whenever they add or delete an interest the app unregisters from the notification hub and subscribes with the new tags.

I thought that this was incorrect, but I can't find a way to see what tags a user is subscribed to, or add/delete a single tag.

In the current app, sometimes our test devices don't receive notifications that I think they should.

I've found answers online saying that you should avoid unregistering, and that there is a delay to register and unregister (such as the answer here, [Android Azure Notification hub unregister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229878/android-azure-notification-hub-unregister))

I am looking for any insight on how to handle this usecase, of adding and deleting tags.

Comment: The comment on lag on unregistration and recommendation to avoid unregistration are referring to gcm not notification hubs at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229878/android-azure-notification-hub-unregister. Notice that user is doing both "gcm.unregister()" as well as "hub.unregister()". The latter is fine to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify how you are communicating with the Azure Notification Hub, I will use the [ANH REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495827.aspx) as reference.

> "...I can't find a way to see what tags a user is subscribed to..."

If you request a registration (e.g. [per registration ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223261.aspx)), you will get the registration data including the assigned tags.

> "...or add/delete a single tag."

You don't add or delete single tags directly on the registration in ANH, you basically update the whole registration, if necessary. Some ANH SDKs may have convenience methods for this, but in general, you just send the complete registration object with the desired tags to ANH and it gets overwritten. E.g. the REST API has an "[Update Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223262.aspx)" method, but no "Add/Remove Tag" methods.

> "I've found answers online saying that you should avoid unregistering, and that there is a delay to register and unregister..."

You should indeed not unregister and register for this use case because of the reasons you stated. This is probably also the reason for:

> "In the current app, sometimes our test devices don't receive notifications that I think they should."

Never unregister and register again for updating a registration. Only unregister, if you don't want to receive notifications at all on a specific device.

> "I am looking for any insight on how to handle this usecase, of adding and deleting tags."

Basically, just omit the "unregister step" and make the "register step" a "[create or update registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495630.aspx) step" using the actual ANH registration ID and all desired tags.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for taking so long to get back. I was using the azureNotificationHub wrapper for iOS on Microsoft's Azure github page. This is working well enough sending test messages now, so thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to have a "deleteTag" api method that just deletes a tag from any and all regs that have it.